# Qt: Two buttons in one, a dice in another window

Tags: c++, qt, button, window, paint

In Qt I'm programming a "game" that shows you a drawn dice with random numbers. It's actually really simple but quite a task for me as newcomer.

So far I've implemented the following widgets, functions and so on:

1) A Button that refers to a slot that picks a random value between 1 and 6

2) A Button that closes the app

3) A drawn dice (painter.drawRoundedRect & painter.drawEllipse for all 6 possibilities).

I want the button 1) and button 2) to be shown in the same window and the dice 3) in another window. However, right now the two buttons are in two each windows and the dice is (correctly) shown in a separate window (as it should be).

If I create a new QGridLayout and I add the button 1) widget to it, it suddenly shows up in the dice window! I'm quite confused how that actually works.

**dicewidget.cpp:**

```
DiceWidget::DiceWidget(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent)
{

    QPushButton *rollDice = new QPushButton("Roll Dice!");
    rollDice->show();

    QPushButton *close = new QPushButton("Close app");
    close->show();

    connect( rollDice, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(randomizer()) );
    connect( close, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit()) );
}


void DiceWidget::paintEvent (QPaintEvent *event)
{

      setMinimumSize(150, 150-BORDER);

      int diceSize = width() < height() ? width(): height();
      diceSize -= 2 * BORDER + 1;

      QPainter painter(this);
      painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing); 
      painter.setPen(Qt::black);                     
      painter.setBrush(Qt::white);         

      painter.drawRoundedRect( ( width() - diceSize ) / 2,
                               ( height() - diceSize ) / 2,
                                 diceSize, diceSize,
                                 15, 15, Qt::RelativeSize);

      painter.setBrush(Qt::black);

      switch(value)
      {
        case 1:
        // SHORTENED: draws the ellipse...
           break;

        case 2:

        // draws one more ellipse... (and so on)  
           break;          

        // ... until value 6

        case 6:

        // draws six ellipses
           break;
      }

}


void DiceWidget::randomizer(void)
{
    value = rand() % 6 + 1;
    update();
}
```

I hope it's not too confusing and you can get an idea of my concept. I searched a lot but I can't find a solution that fits to my application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you have seen button 1) in the dice window is because you obviously created the GridLayout in the constructor of DiceWidget and set its parent to be `this` (the DiceWidget). Therefore your dice window gets the gridLayout and when you add your button to the layout it will therefore appear together with your dice in the same window.

Add the following to your DiceWidget constructor:

```cpp
DiceWidget::DiceWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QPushButton *rollDice = new QPushButton("Roll Dice!");
    QPushButton *close = new QPushButton("Close app");

    QWidget *buttonWindow = new QWidget;
    QGridLayout *diceLayout = new QGridLayout(buttonWindow);
    diceLayout->addWidget(rollDice, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    diceLayout->addWIdget(close, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    buttonWindow->show();

    connect( rollDice, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(randomizer()) );
    connect( close, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit()) );
}
```